# Run JAVA+Cucumber+JUnit Maven project in command line

Tags: java, maven, junit, cucumber

I am with a small problem here: run this project using MAVEN and Cucumber.

I'm with the following structure in my MAVEN project:

````
```
br.com.home.cucumberProjectWithWS
                |--- src/tests/java
                |                             |--- com.home.Model (secret)
                |                             |--- com.home.Control (secret)
                |                             |--- com.home.View
                                               |                             |--- ... (secret)
                                               |                             |--- Runner.java
                |                             |--- com.home.javaStepsFolder
                |                                                             |--- MyTestsSteps.java
                |--- src/main/java
                |--- src/main/resources
                |--- src/tests/resources
                |--- featuresFolder
                |                             |--- FirstFeature.feature
                |                             |--- SecondFeature.feature
                |                             |--- ThirdFeature.feature
                |--- pom.xml
```
````

The `Runner.java` class is the following:

````
```
package br.com.home.runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(monochrome = false, plugin = { "html:target/cucumber-html-report", "json:target/cucumber.json",
                               "pretty:target/cucumber-pretty.txt", "usage:target/cucumber-usage.json",
                               "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml" }, features = "featuresFolder", glue = { "br.com.home.javaStepsFolder" })
public class Runner {

}
```
````

The class `MyTestsSteps.java` is something like the following:

````
```
package br.com.home.runner;

import cucumber.api.*;

class MyTestsSteps{

                Scenario scenario;
                Controller controller = new Control();

                @Before
                public void doItBefore(Scenario scenario){
                               this.scenario = scenario;
                }

                @When("^we do something$")
                public void doSomething(){
                               controller.doSomething();
                }

                @When("^we do something else$")
                public void doSomethingElse(){
                               controller.doSomethingElse();
                }

                @Then("^we expect \"([^\"]*)$")
                public void weExpectSomeResult(String result){
                               assertTrue(controller.getResultExpected().equals(result));
                }
}
```

And my `pom.xml` is the following:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
                <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
                <groupId>com.home.cucumberProjectWithWS</groupId>
                <artifactId>com.home.cucumberProjectWithWS</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

                <dependencies>
                               <!-- CUCUMBER -->

                               <!-- CUCUMBER: Java -->

                               <dependency>
                                               <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                                               <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
                                               <version>1.2.4</version>
                                               <scope>test</scope>
                               </dependency>

                               <!-- CUCUMBER: Core -->
                               <dependency>
                                               <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                                               <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
                                               <version>1.2.4</version>
                               </dependency>

                               <!-- CUCUMBER: JUnit -->
                               <dependency>
                                               <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                                               <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
                                               <version>1.2.4</version>
                                               <scope>test</scope>
                               </dependency>

                               <!-- CUCUMBER: JVM Deps -->
                               <dependency>
                                               <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                                               <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
                                               <version>1.0.5</version>
                               </dependency>

                               <!-- CUCUMBER: Reports -->
                               <dependency>
                                               <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
                                               <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
                                               <version>2.5.0</version>
                               </dependency>

                               <!-- CUCUMBER: Gherkin -->
                               <dependency>
                                               <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
                                               <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
                                               <version>2.12.2</version>
                               </dependency>

                               <!-- MOCKITO: All -->
                               <dependency>
                                               <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                                               <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                                               <version>1.10.19</version>
                               </dependency>

                               <!-- JUNIT -->
                               <dependency>
                                               <groupId>junit</groupId>
                                               <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                                               <version>4.11</version>
                                               <scope>test</scope>
                               </dependency>
                </dependencies>


                <build>
                               <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
                               <plugins>
                                               <plugin>
                                                               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                                                               <version>3.3</version>
                                                               <configuration>
                                                                               <source>1.8</source>
                                                                               <target>1.8</target>
                                                                               <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                                               </configuration>
                                               </plugin>

                                               <plugin>
                                                               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                                               <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                                                               <version>2.19.1</version>
                                                               <configuration>
                                                                               <properties>
                                                                                              <property>
                                                                                                              <name>junit</name>
                                                                                                              <value>true</value>
                                                                                              </property>
                                                                               </properties>
                                                                               <includes>
                                                                                              <include>**/*Runner.java</include>
                                                                               </includes>
                                                               </configuration>
                                               </plugin>

                               </plugins>
                </build>

</project>
```
````

I try to run:

````
```
mvn clean test
```
````

And it does not works.

I want to run those tests using Maven and know if is possible set the sequence of execution of Cucumber Tests.

I have tried to define in @CucumberOptions features parameter, but it did not work!

````
```
features = "{featuresFolder/FirstFeature.feature, featuresFolder/SecondFeature.feature}"
```
````

and

````
```
features = {
                "featuresFolder/FirstFeature.feature", 
                "featuresFolder/SecondFeature.feature"
}
```
````

And tries to do (as recommended in other post here):

````
```
<includes>
                <exclude>**/*Runner.java</exclude>
</includes>
```
````

in `pom.xml` surefire-plugin configuration.

But it did not work too.

Someone could help me to run this project using MAVEN command line and Cucumber if possible.

I am using Windows 8.1!
And the project will run in Linux in future.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried placing your feature files inside 'src/tests/resources/features/', and update the features attribute within the cucumber options?

Comment: You need to rename your Runner.java to something that ends with Test keyword or has Test in it or ends with TestCase. Only then surefire plugin picks this automatically. Otherwise you will need to add this in configurations in pom.xml.

Comment: Dear @JamesMcGuigan, thank you for your answer, firstly. But it does not works. Maven returns error in Cucumber Annotations. For example: `cannot find symbol. symbol: class When location: br.com.home.javaStepsFolder`.

Comment: Dear @Grasshopper, thak you for your answer, firstly. But it doesn't works too. :/ I rename the  `Runner.java` by `TestRunner.java` and it does not works too.

Comment: @user2732966 Can you try removing Runner exclusion pattern in pom.xml for surefire plugin and trying. It should pick up automatically. In includes you have put in an excludes pattern in your pom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the path where your Pom.xml is situated. Then execute the command below.

Command to run maven, cucumber tests from command prompt.

**mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="path/to/feature-files --tags @Your_tag"**

Comment: thank you @dsbonafe for accepting the answer. Hope your issue resolved.

Comment: **NOTE: THE ABOVE `-Dcucumber.options` USAGE IS DEPRECATED**. Please find the updated one here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68437296/10804821

Answer (score 3):

I have solved the problem.
I remove the surefire plugin, update my project and run:
After I have restructured the project:

-- Features file should be on /src/resource/feature.
-- Java file should be on /src/test/java and should have the name Steps.java.

`$ mvn clean install
$ mvn -Dtest=RunnerTest test`

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the below is deprecated. [refer here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/release-notes/v5.0.0.md#property-based-options)

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="path/to/feature-files --tags @Your_tag"
```

The updated equivalent for above is

```
mvn clean test -Dcucumber.feature="path/to/feature-files" -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@Your_tag"
```

- **Note:** The `path/to/feature-files` can also contain sub directories with `.feature` files.

Please [refer here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/main/release-notes/v5.0.0.md#property-based-options) to explore more on CLI options

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how I used CucumberJVM in a small project.

https://github.com/modernmaster/katas/blob/develop/rock-paper-scissors/

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me as well after running below command

mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="src/ressouces/features --tags @@Your_tag"